# How do I rename columns for a many to many table with composite keys using EF CTP5 code-first?

Tags: many-to-many, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

Here is the sample from the ADO.NET site.

Rename columns in many:many table:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>() 
.HasMany(p => p.Tags)
.WithMany(t => t.Products)
.Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey(p => p.ProductId, "CustomFkToProductId");
        m.MapRightKey(t => t.TagId, "CustomFkToTagId");
    });
```

Please extend this example with a second imaginary key (i.e. ProductId2, TagId2) on each of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

For that you just need to map the secondary columns as well:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
            .WithMany(t => t.Products) 
            .Map(m => 
            { 
                m.MapLeftKey(p => p.ProductId, "CustomFkToProductId");
                m.MapLeftKey(p => p.ProductId2, "CustomFkToProductId2");
                m.MapRightKey(t => t.TagId, "CustomFkToTagId"); 
                m.MapRightKey(t => t.TagId2, "CustomFkToTagId2"); 
            });
```

Comment: @Morteza-Manavi I tried this. I am getting following error `Number of Properties in the Dependent and Principal Role in a relationship constraint must be exactly identical.` I have 3 columns on both sides in my Many:Many table

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna Rallabhandi: Could you show your code possibly in a new thread?